# how to fetch data from multiple tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking some help in php+MySQL+jquery
I have 2 tables

**table1**
table 1 have 4 colume
(id, title, desc, thumb_img)

**tabel2**
table 2 have 3 colume(id, table1id, img)

I just want to compare 2 table with the value of $_get['QS'];
and show the records from both (title, desc, img)

Looking forward for the help.:)

Comment: This is from the Postgres manual, but it may help you: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.desc, t2.img
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.id=t2.table1id
WHERE somefieldyoudidntspecify=:qs
```

Comment: somefieldyoudidntspecify? 
can u explan this?

Comment: It's whatever you want to compare `$_GET['QS']` with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
   $query="select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t2.table1id = t1.id where SomeField = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_get['QS'])."'"
?>
```

Comment: @faisal: Perhaps only you can answer that. :) You need to specify what you want to compare against $_get['QS']

Comment: yeah, just replace somefield with one of your table fields.  you just didn't specify which field should be compared against, so i made up a fake one.