# How to fetch data from 2 different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Subscriber_detail

SubscriberID | Merchant_ID 
23           |  24

User_Detail

User_ID | User_RegisteredID

23      | 1001001
24      | 1001002
```

Need to fetch `User_RegisteredID` from `User_Login` table for `SubscriberID and Merchant_ID from Subscriber_Detail`

Comment: Why do people not Google these things?

Comment: @Jared bcoz we people are always here to comment and response to these type of questions ;)

Comment: @swapnesh Surely it's been answered here before...

Comment: see those link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011843/how-to-fetch-data-from-multiple-tables-mysql?rq=1   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267069/mysql-query-to-fetch-data-from-multiple-tables?rq=1

Comment: @Jared If not thousand at-least hundred traces can easily be found

Comment: @All Stop fighting this QA forums not fight club.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  sub.User_RegisteredID AS SubscriberRegisteredID,
        mer.User_RegisteredID AS MerchantRegisteredID
FROM    Subscriber_detail s
        JOIN User_Detail sub on s.SubscriberID = sub.User_ID
        JOIN User_Detail mer ON s.Merchant_ID = mer.User_ID
```

You need to join both tables and table `User_Detail` should be join two times because there are two columns in table `Subscriber_detail` that are referenced to it.

If one column is *NULLABLE*, `LEFT JOIN` should be used instead.

```
SELECT  sub.User_RegisteredID AS SubscriberRegisteredID,
        mer.User_RegisteredID AS MerchantRegisteredID
FROM    Subscriber_detail s
        LEFT JOIN User_Detail sub on s.SubscriberID = sub.User_ID
        LEFT JOIN User_Detail mer ON s.Merchant_ID = mer.User_ID
```